# Update Data Table to Reflect Multiple Selection - R Shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I currently have a dynamic app in R using Shiny that displays a data table on another tab based on the user selection in the first tab. The code for this is below

```
rm(list=ls())
library(shiny)
library(RODBC)
library(DT)
library(openxlsx)
ui <- bootstrapPage(titlePanel("Financial Planning Client Discovery Form"),
                                    
  
  tabsetPanel( id = "Main Panel", tabPanel("Client Selection",
  
  textInput(inputId = "First_Name",
              label = "First Name",
              value = "",
              width = NULL,
              placeholder = "Enter Client's First Name"),
  textInput(inputId = "Last_Name",
            label = "Last Name",
            value = "",
            width = NULL,
            placeholder = "Enter Client's Last Name"),
  textInput(inputId = "SSN",
            label = "Social Security Number",
            value = "",
            width = NULL,
            placeholder = "Enter Client's SSN (XXXXXXXXX)"),
  
  DT::dataTableOutput("MyTable")
  
), tabPanel("Client Discovery Form Information",downloadButton("downloadData","Export Data"), DT::dataTableOutput("CDFInfo"),DT::dataTableOutput("WealthSummary"), DT::dataTableOutput("Deposit"),DT::dataTableOutput("Investment"),DT::dataTableOutput("Loan"),
             DT::dataTableOutput("Other"))))

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  BDW <- odbcConnect("BDW", uid="", pwd="", believeNRows = FALSE)
  BOSCDB <- odbcConnect("BOSCDB", uid="", pwd="", believeNRows = FALSE)
  
  table1 <- reactive({sqlQuery(BDW,paste0("
                      SELECT DISTINCT a.PartyID, FullName as 'Name',TaxID as 'Social Security Number', AddressLine1+' '+City+' '+StateCode+' '+PostalCode as 'Address'
  FROM [EnterpriseCustomer].[dbo].[Party]a
  LEFT JOIN [EnterpriseCustomer].[dbo].[PartytoAddressRelationship]b ON b.PartyID = a.PartyID
  LEFT JOIN [EnterpriseCustomer].[dbo].[Address]c ON c.AddressID = b.AddressID
  WHERE FullName like '",input$First_Name,"%'
  and FullName like '%",input$Last_Name,"'
  and TaxID like '%",input$SSN,"%'
  and a.ActiveRecordIndicator = 1
  and b.ActiveRecordIndicator = 1
  and c.ActiveRecordIndicator = 1"), as.is = TRUE)})
  
  
  output$MyTable = DT::renderDataTable({table1()}, caption = 'Client Selection',options = list(searching = FALSE, pageLength = 15,list(className = 'dt-left')), selection = 'multiple', rownames = FALSE)
  
  table2 <- reactive({
    row <- input$MyTable_rows_selected
    sqlQuery(BDW,paste0("SELECT DISTINCT FullName as 'Name',DATEDIFF(hour,DateofBirthorIncorporation,GETDATE())/8766 as 'Age',CONVERT(varchar(10),DateofBirthorIncorporation, 120) as 'Date of Birth',TaxID as 'SSN',GenderCode as 'Gender', OccupationCodeDescription as 'Occupation',DigitalAddress as 'Email', AddressLine1+' '+City+' '+StateCode+' '+PostalCode as 'Address'
  FROM [EnterpriseCustomer].[dbo].[Party]a
  LEFT JOIN [EnterpriseCustomer].[dbo].[PartytoAddressRelationship]b ON b.PartyID = a.PartyID
  LEFT JOIN [EnterpriseCustomer].[dbo].[Address]c ON c.AddressID = b.AddressID
  LEFT JOIN [EnterpriseCustomer].[dbo].[PartytoDigitalAddressRelationship]d ON d.PartyID = a.PartyID
  LEFT JOIN [EnterpriseCustomer].[dbo].[DigitalAddress]e ON e.DigitalAddressID = d.DigitalAddressID
  LEFT JOIN [BDW].[EnterpriseCustomer].[PartyOccupationCodes]g ON a.OccupationCode = g.OccupationCode
  WHERE
  a.PartyID =",table1()[row,"PartyID"],"
  and (AddressLine1+' '+City+' '+StateCode+' '+PostalCode) like '%",table1()[row,"Address"],"%'
  and a.ActiveRecordIndicator = 1 and b.ActiveRecordIndicator = 1"), as.is = TRUE)})
  
  table8 <- reactive({
    row <- input$MyTable_rows_selected
  sqlQuery(BOSCDB,paste0("SELECT DISTINCT TaxID, ltrim(rtrim(MinimumAnnualIncomeAmount))+' - '+ltrim(rtrim(MaximumAnnualIncomeAmount)) as 'Annual Income Band',ltrim(rtrim(MinimumNetWorthAmount))+' - '+ltrim(rtrim(MaximumNetWorthAmount)) as 'Net Worth Band',ltrim(rtrim(MinLiquidNetWorthAmt))+' - '+ltrim(rtrim(MaxLiquidNetWorthAmt)) as 'Liquid Net Worth Band'
  FROM [ExternalData_Stage].[dbo].[tblPrsCustomerAccount_G]a
  LEFT JOIN [ExternalData_Stage].[dbo].[tblPrsCustomerAccount_H]b ON b.AccountNumber = a.AccountNumber
  WHERE TaxID = '",table1()[row,"Social Security Number"],"'
  and a.DataDate = (SELECT MAX(DataDate) FROM [ExternalData_Stage].[dbo].[tblPrsCustomerAccount_G] WHERE TaxID = '",table1()[row,"Social Security Number"],"')"),as.is = TRUE)})
    
  table9 <- reactive({merge(table2(),table8(), by.x = "SSN", by.y = "TaxID", all.x = TRUE)})
  
  observeEvent(input$MyTable_rows_selected, {  
  output$CDFInfo <- DT:: renderDataTable({table9()},options = list(dom='t'), caption = 'Client Information', rownames = FALSE)
    updateTabsetPanel(session, "Main Panel", selected = "Client Discovery Form Information")
  })
```

Up to this point the code has only supported single selection; however, I'm wanting to change it over to multiple selection. I changed the main selection table (MyTable) over to multiple selection which is working, but table 9 is still just showing only one selection worth of data. It will only show which individual I select first on the first tab. I'm wanting to show a data table of both individuals combined in a data table. Thanks for all of the help ahead of time!

Comment: Please provide a [reproducible minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269/8107362)

Comment: How do you do this with a shiny app @mnist?

Comment: strip the app down to a simple example that reflects the same structure and reproduces the problem